# Difference between IOP and iEthernet?

Tags: ethernet

WIZnet (https://www.wiznet.io) offers various ethernet solutions for embedded systems.

They have a product range, which seems evolving as their numbers are increasing, ie:

> W5100 < W5300 < W5500 < W5500S < W6100

These are all "iEthernet" SoCs.

However they also have another category: IOP (Internet Offload Processor):

> W7500

Both categories seem to have the integrated Ethernet MAC, and I'm quite confused:

What is the difference between `W7500` and `W5500`?

Is `W7500` better recommended to use instead of `W5500` for new designs?

Comment: What information you need that is not available from the manufacturer of these devices? Also we don't know which product is more ecommended for your new design, as we don't know anything about your new design.

Comment: The IOP appears to be targeted at applications such as firewalls where it can, literally, offload some of the processing from the main application. As such, it doesn't seem to fit into the same number sequence as the other SOCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the the Wiznet website, the IOP have a Cortex-M0 processor in addition to the 'hardwired' tcp stack with ethernet. There's a 32k block of ram shared between the two devices.

The other chips require the addition of an external microcontroller.